# What's the difference between step sequence and flow in spring batch configuration?

Tags: configuration, spring-batch

I was reading spring io document.

the document shows two different examples

5.3.1 Sequential Flow

```
<job id="job">
    <step id="stepA" parent="s1" next="stepB" />
    <step id="stepB" parent="s2" next="stepC"/>
    <step id="stepC" parent="s3" />
</job>
```

and

5.3.6 Externalizing Flow Definitions and Dependencies Between Jobs

```
<job id="job">
    <flow id="job1.flow1" parent="flow1" next="step3"/>
    <step id="step3" parent="s3"/>
</job>

<flow id="flow1">
    <step id="step1" parent="s1" next="step2"/>
    <step id="step2" parent="s2"/>
</flow>
```

what's the difference between using some steps and some flows having some steps?

I'm in confusion. Please help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second form allow you to reuse `flow1` in another job.

```
<job id="job2">
    <flow id="job2.flow1" parent="flow1" next="job2.step3"/>
    <step id="job2.step3" parent="s3"/>
</job>
```

From official doc:

> The effect of defining an external flow like this is simply to insert
>   the steps from the external flow into the job as if they had been
>   declared inline. In this way many jobs can refer to the same template
>   flow and compose such templates into different logical flows. This is
>   also a good way to separate the integration testing of the individual
>   flows